# Python factorization program

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, factorization

I'm new to programming and I am trying to write a program that takes a positive integer n from input, and then outputs all factorizations of n.

For example if n=10 the program would output 
1 times 10 equals 10 
2 times 5 equals 10 
5 times 2 equals 10 
10 times 1 equals 10

I believe the easiest way to do it is to use an if statement nested within for loops. Can anybody provide me with any guidance to help create this? So far I have...

```
n = int(input())
a = 0
b = n
for a in range(0, n):
    if a * b !=n:
      continue
    if a * b ==n:
      print (a+ "times" +b+ "equals" +n)
    a=a+1
    b=n-1
```

But for some reason it isn't working. I think I have the right general idea but my code is obviously incorrect.

Comment: You appear not to have attempted this - StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, not general help. Try to implement this, then come back and ask a question if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, but also with your logic. You are increasing `a` twice (with `for` and addition), `b` becomes `n-1` the first time through the loop and stays that way, but even if it didn't (eg `b = b - 1`), it wouldn't work, because if you are increasing `a` and decreasing `b` simultaneously, you won't find the correct values unless they happen to match by chance.

Other than that, it's unnecessary to check for `a * b != n`, you need to call `str` on the integers to add them to strings and the 0 in your `range` call is redundant.

whncode's answer is an elegant solution (except for a couple of errors I tried to correct), but to use your logic, you might do this:

```
for a in range(1, n+1):
    for b in range(1, n+1):
        if a * b == n:
            print str(a) + " times " + str(b) + " equals " + str(n)
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much Paulo really appreciate that. Im still struggling to get to grips with Python atm. I have never done any programming before so i'm trying to work myself through a series of challenges some of which I am managing to do with ease others you can clearly see struggling with. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 10
for divisor in range(n, 0, -1): # reverse range
    if (n%divisor == 0):       # if modulo is 0
        print("%d times %d equals %d", (n/divisor, divisor, n)
```